# Dictionary within for loop does not transfer to outside for loop - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to make a dictionary from values in a reference .txt file, but when i make the dictionary and print it, within the for loop I get the desired result:

```
    ref = open("reference.txt", "r")
    contents = ref.read().splitlines()

    for line in contents:
        data = line.split(",")
        i = iter(data)
        newData = dict(zip(i, i))
        print(newData)

    Output:
    {"Bob's Diner": '001100111'}
    {"Jim's Grill": '001100111'}
    {"Tommy's Burger Shack": '01011101'}
```

But when I put the print statement outside the for loop, I get a different result:

```
    ref = open("reference.txt", "r")
    contents = ref.read().splitlines()

    for line in contents:
        data = line.split(",")
        i = iter(data)
        newData = dict(zip(i, i))

    print(newData)

    Output:
    {"Tommy's Burger Shack": '01011101'}
```

How can I fix this so that it compiles it into one collective, usable dictionary?

Comment: consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 7):

In your code `newData` is pointing to a new dictionary in each loop iteration, just create a dict outside and update it:

```
newData = {}
for line in contents:
    data = line.split(",")
    i = iter(data)
    newData.update(dict(zip(i, i)))

print(newData)
```

Comment: Great answer, but I wonder about: “`newData` is in the loop scope.” That implies that the variable is out of the local scope, which it clearly is not, or `print(newData)` would raise an exception.

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston, I referred to the question code. Where he had the variable living inside the loop.

Comment: Right, but in the question code (and in general) the loop scope and local scope are the same

Comment: yeah, I get what you mean. I did not explain myself properly here. It is a matter of missinterpretation

Comment: I’m just nitpicking. Regardless, great answer!

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But you were right, I was not explaining it properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're making a new dictionary upon every iteration of the loop. Defining the dict outside the loop will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to create a dictionary before the loop starts so the data can be stored there and be pulled out for the print statement.

```
ref = open("reference.txt", "r")
contents = ref.read().splitlines()

newData = {}
for line in contents:
    data = line.split(",")
    i = iter(data)
    newData = dict(zip(i, i))

print(newData)
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem that a new dictionary is created each time and overwrites the previous one. Only the last update is kept.